Saving name of length in TikZ
In the following statement I make use of custom coordinates points to draw a circle. I calculated the radius using let expression and save the length as \n1 within scope for plotting. What is the recommended way to save the length as variable \n1length (globally) so that it is available for drawing downstream in commands that accept length, or for general use ?
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.shapes}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label={right:T}] (T) at (0, 0);
\coordinate[label={right:M}] (M) at (0, 1);
\coordinate[label={right:N}] (N) at (0, -1);
\path[draw] let \p1 = ($(T) - (N)$), \p2 = ($(M) - (N)$), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)+veclen(\x2, \y2)} in (N) circle (\n1);

\foreach \i in {T,M,N} {
  \filldraw[black] (\i) circle (0.4pt);
}

%% suppose i want to create a decorated path with same radius as \n1 above.
% \draw[decoration=zigzag,decorate,fill=blue!30] (N) circle [radius=\n1length];


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You can use \pgfextra{\xdef\nIlength{\n1}}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label={right:T}] (T) at (0, 0);
\coordinate[label={right:M}] (M) at (0, 1);
\coordinate[label={right:N}] (N) at (0, -1);
\path[draw] let \p1 = ($(T) - (N)$), \p2 = ($(M) - (N)$), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)+veclen(\x2, \y2)} in \pgfextra{\xdef\nIlength{\n1}} (N) circle (\n1);

\foreach \i in {T,M,N} {
  \filldraw[black] (\i) circle (0.4pt);
}

%% suppose i want to create a decorated path with same radius as \n1 above.

\draw[decoration=zigzag,decorate,fill=blue!30,opacity=0.5] (N) circle [radius=\nIlength];


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


